# WPF: How do I set a UI Element's background property to null/nothing/default in XAML?

Tags: wpf, xaml, background, storyboard

Using code, I can set a UI element's background property to its default value by setting it to `nothing`, i.e.

```
myControl.Background = Nothing
```

But how do I do this in XAML?  In particular, I'm doing this in a Storyboard:

```
<Storyboard>
    <ColorAnimation 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
        Duration="00:00:02.00" 
        To="DEFAULT_COLOR_HERE" />
</Storyboard>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot

```
<Storyboard>
    <ColorAnimation 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
        Duration="00:00:02.00" 
        To="{x:Null}" />
</Storyboard>
```

Comment: Awesome, that works.  Thanks.  Related question, how does one do this in a key frame?  It doesn't like {x:Null} there.  e.g. <LinearColorKeyFrame Value="DEFAULT_COLOR_HERE"  KeyTime="0:0:2" />

Comment: I've posted the key frame problem as a new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691560